# Ionic 2 Ecommerce Dynamically Calculate Amount

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am developing E-commerce app.

I need to dynamically calculate Amount.

Here is my Html code.

I have `Cartproducts` value in array.And display list of product using *ngfor.

```
<div class="cart" >

        <div>
            <ion-row class="product-in-cart" padding *ngFor="let p of Cartproducts;let i=index">
                <ion-col col-4 class="pic-blk">
                    <img class="pic-image" src="{{p.P_IMAGES[0].URL}}" alt="product2">

                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col col-4 class="minus">
                            <button ion-button outline small><ion-icon name="remove" (click)="countOperator(-1,p,i)"></ion-icon></button>
                        </ion-col>

                        <ion-col col-4 class="label">
                            <ion-label text-center *ngIf="Pid != p.C_ID || count <= 1">1</ion-label>
                            <ion-label text-center *ngIf="Pid == p.C_ID && count > 1">{{count}}</ion-label>
                        </ion-col>

                         <ion-col col-4 class="plus">
                            <button ion-button outline small><ion-icon name="add" (click)="countOperator(1,p,i)"></ion-icon></button>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>  
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-8 class="pic-details">
                    <h1>{{p.P_TITLE}}</h1>
                    <p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
                    <p class="code">Code: 123</p>

                    <ion-row class="price-blk"> 
                        <ion-col width-50 class="product-per-price"><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee" >{{p.PRICE_SALE}} <em>/ Unit</em></ion-col>

                        <ion-col width-50 text-right class="product-full-price" ><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee" *ngIf="Price == i">{{count * p.PRICE_SALE}}</ion-col>
                    </ion-row>

                    <div class="cancel">
                        <button (click)="cancel(i)">Cancel X</button>
                    </div>
                </ion-col>  
            </ion-row>
        </div>

        <div padding class="apply-coupon-blk">  
            <p class="blk-text-title">Apply Coupon</p>

            <ion-row class="apply-coupon">
                <ion-col col-8>
                    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Type coupon code"></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-4>
                    <button ion-button block class="apply-btn">Apply</button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </div>

        <div padding class="price-summary-blk">
            <p class="blk-text-title">Price Details</p>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>Sub Total</ion-col>
                <ion-col text-right><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">4000</ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>Estimated Tax(%)</ion-col>
                <ion-col text-right><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">200</ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row padding-top class="total">
                <ion-col>Total</ion-col>
                <ion-col text-right><img src="./assets/images/rupee-black.svg" alt="Rupee">4200</ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my template.

[image]

If I need Increase the product quantity in the first product(Martina).

So I click the `+` Icon and increase the product quantity.I displayed the amount using `{{count * p.PRICE_SALE}}`.But Amount will be changed Both of product.

I need also calculate the `SubTotal` and `Total`

Here is my countOperator method

```
countOperator(operator,s,i){

    if(this.count >= 1){
      this.show1=false;
      this.count += operator;
    }
    if(this.count < 1){
      this.show1=false;
      this.count = 1;
    }
  }
```

Here is my Cart product Array

```
 [
  {
    "P_ID": 1,
    "C_ID": 1,
    "SKU": 0,
    "P_TITLE": "Martina",
    "P_TYPE": "simple",
    "P_DESCRIPTION": "Commodo adipisicing officia non excepteur officia nostrud. Eu voluptate amet elit nulla.",
    "P_STOCK": 100,
    "PRICE_REGULAR": 194,
    "PRICE_SALE": 161,
    "P_ATTR": [
      {}
    ],
    "P_IMAGES": [
      {
        "URL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/sparkler.svg?alt=media&token=5fde41cc-2c6c-4dcc-9749-59dda751206b"
      },
      {
        "URL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/sparkler.svg?alt=media&token=5fde41cc-2c6c-4dcc-9749-59dda751206b"
      }
    ],
    "P_STATUS": "Active",
    "id": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b84"
  },
  {
    "P_ID": 2,
    "C_ID": 1,
    "SKU": 1,
    "P_TITLE": "Kristen",
    "P_TYPE": "simple",
    "P_DESCRIPTION": "Laborum cupidatat dolor tempor cillum incididunt in veniam nisi dolore.",
    "P_STOCK": 100,
    "PRICE_REGULAR": 130,
    "PRICE_SALE": 174,
    "P_ATTR": [
      {}
    ],
    "P_IMAGES": [
      {
        "URL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/sparklers-brothers-18-inch-large-gold-sparklers-pack-of-10-1_large.jpeg?alt=media&token=28b1be61-f346-4801-8300-9f0a86a5942f"
      },
      {
        "URL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/sparklers-brothers-18-inch-large-gold-sparklers-pack-of-10-1_large.jpeg?alt=media&token=28b1be61-f346-4801-8300-9f0a86a5942f"
      }
    ],
    "P_STATUS": "Active",
    "id": "595f3e418c4d19b50ac21b85"
  },
  {
    "P_ID": 3,
    "C_ID": 1,
    "SKU": 2,
    "P_TITLE": "Jayne",
    "P_TYPE": "simple",
    "P_DESCRIPTION": "Anim ad et sunt aliquip proident fugiat deserunt.",
    "P_STOCK": 100,
    "PRICE_REGULAR": 215,
    "PRICE_SALE": 184,
    "P_ATTR": [
      {}
    ],
    "P_IMAGES": [
      {
        "URL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/Sparklers2502502.jpg?alt=media&token=979a1c5f-4e5c-4dbf-8d8a-e2358b6e1001"
      },
      {
        "URL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/Sparklers2502502.jpg?alt=media&token=979a1c5f-4e5c-4dbf-8d8a-e2358b6e1001"
      }
    ],
    "P_STATUS": "Active",
    "id": "595f3e428c4d19b50ac21b86"
  }
]
```

I have No idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: You are using a single count variable for all products? If yes then that is bad and you need to manage count for every product. plunker would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have no idea.Ya, i am using single count for every product.How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you paste here your Cartproducts array?

Comment: I can fix the code if you can share component and template code here or a plunker.

Comment: @FahadNisar.Kindly check I update My Question and also add Cartproducts array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that you can follow to achieve this:

- Add a count attribute in your **`Cartproducts`** array.
- Update that count attribute for the selected product in your
  **`countOperator()`** function.
- Replace `{{count * p.PRICE_SALE}}` with `{{p.count * p.PRICE_SALE}}`

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.I have one doubt.How to update count attribute in Cartproducts array.

Comment: you are passing object as p in the function. So you can access the count variable like p.count and can increment and decrement as required.
p.count = p.count + 1; or p.count = p.count - 1;   This will only work if you first add count attribute for every product in array.

Comment: please try it and let me know if it works. (You may mark my answer as accepted if it works :))

Comment: Are u there?I followed this step.But does not update count value in UI.why?But I Update the count value in the array.

Comment: wait. Let me create a plunker for you.

Comment: Thats great. Meanwhile here is the working plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/c4JD8xjApU1yqdzgX3nA?p=preview